# Is there a knot invariant that is not the sum of finite type invariants

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

It is an open question whether finite type invariants separate knots, but do we know any knot invariant that is NOT the "sum" of finite type invariants? For instance, many knot polynomials, while not finite type themselves, are a "sum" of finite type invariants of all degrees.

(Disclaimer, I get this isn't a direct sum, so what I'm asking is if the group of knot invariants is direct product of finite type invariants of all degrees in some sense)

Comment: How about the knot group?

Comment: I don't think this is a well-posed question, largely because of the vagueness of the term "invariants".  Qiaochu has already pointed out that many useful invariants don't take numerical values.  If you insist on numerical invariants, a random bijection between the set of knots and $\mathbb{Z}$ is a perfectly fine invariant.

Comment: @Andy: well, we might insist on an invariant explicitly computable from a knot diagram.

Comment: @Andy that's a fair point. Perhaps I can amend my question to be: Are there any well known knot Z valued invariants that can't be broken up as a sum like that.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: That's still not much of a restriction.  We've known how to solve the isomorphism problem for knots since Ancient Times (more precisely: we learned how to solve the homeomorphism problem for Haken manifolds like knot complements in the 70's and learned that knots are determined by their complement in the 80's), so all you're ruling out are non-computable enumerations.  There really isn't a way to define "invariants" except for ways that make this question "obviously false" or "obviously true".

Comment: @AndyPutman: I think it becomes much more interesting if one asks for *efficiently* computable invariants (say, in polynomial time, or $\mathsf{NP}$, or $\mathsf{PSPACE}$, or others...). But then rather than "obviously false" or "obviously true," it becomes more like "obviously a hard question at the intersection of complexity and topology".

Comment: Is there some nice category of knots where it is an interesting question to ask about certain restricted types of functors from that category to abelian categories? (And where it would capture many of the known knot invariants.)

Comment: If you specify something like "knot invariants satisfying a skein relation" the answer might even be yes. But that's fairly restrictive, since AFAIK every such invariant is a quantum invariant. You would still have to be careful about what you mean by "skein relation."

Answer (score 3):

Here's an expansion on Qiaochu's objection: *homomorphism-counting invariants*.
If $G$ is a finite group and $K$ is a knot, the size of the set $N(G,K) := |\hom(\pi_1(S^3 \setminus K), G)|$ is a $\mathbb Z$-valued invariant of $K$.

For example, $N(D_{2n},K)$ is the number of *Fox $n$-colorings* of $K$ (for $n$ odd.) I read somewhere that one of the best invariants for knot tabulation before the discovery of the quantum invariants was $N(G,K)$ for groups like $SL_n(F_p)$ (or similar, I don't remember at the moment.)

As far as I know, these invariants aren't a sum of finite-type invariants.
This is somewhat surprising from a physical perspective, because $N(G,K)$ is the value of the Dijkgraaf-Witten theory with gauge group $G$ on the knot complement. Dijkgraaf-Witten theory is the discrete version of Chern-Simons theory, which is what underlies quantum knot invariants, hence most finite-type invariants.